# is it possible to programatically "uncheck" showed layers in a folium map after rendering the map? (for performance reasons)

Tags: python, folium

I've run into an interesting problem with folium (python 3.95, folium 0.12.1.post1)

The following code renders the map very fast:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[35.11567262307692,-89.97423444615382], zoom_start=12, tiles='Stamen Terrain')

for i in range(200):
    feature_group = folium.FeatureGroup(i, show=True)
    feature_group.add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

However, if show is set to False, it takes much longer to render.

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[35.11567262307692,-89.97423444615382], zoom_start=12, tiles='Stamen Terrain')

for i in range(200):
    feature_group = folium.FeatureGroup(i, show=False)
    feature_group.add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

The problem is, I don't want these layers shown by default. So I'm wondering if there's a way to render the map, and then automatically uncheck the layers.

Failing that, are there any other ways to deal with this performance issue?

Thanks very much for any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

As per the following threads:

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1506

https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/reference.html

and

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356957/turn-layer-off-by-default-in-leaflet-layercontrol

you can set your `FeatureGroupSubGroup` as unchecked by applying  show=False to the code.

```
 su13 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(surv, "LA", show=False)
 m.add_child(su13)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I reported the issue a couple years ago, and it recently has been fixed:

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1573

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/1690